# Changing repository in a codeship project

Tags: bitbucket, codeship

I have created a project in Codeship using a repository from github. When i try to change it to a bitbucket repository, I get the following error.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHMlh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's currently not possible to switch providers for a Codeship project via the UI. You can either create a new project connected to the Bitbucket repository and copy over the settings or get in touch via https://helpdesk.codeship.com and we can make that change for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the response from support executive

> Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the source repository to
>   another SCM. It needs to be created as a new project.
>
> You can add it as a new project and then copy over the setup and test
>   steps from the old project. You can then remove the old project when
>   ready under Project Settings > General.